# Laravel Passport throwing error in AuthServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-5.8

I am not using default laravel authentication from App\User.

Below are my codes

**App\Models\User**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Helpers\SlugController;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
    //
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $visible = ['name', 'slug'];
    protected $fillable =['name', 'slug', 'email', 'password'];

    public function setSlugAttribute($value){
      $slug = new SlugController;
      $this->attributes['slug'] = !empty($value)?$slug->create($this, $value)
                                                :$slug->create($this, $this->attributes['name']);
    }
    public function setPasswordAttribute($value){
      $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
    }
}
```

**config\auth.php**

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],


    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

**app\Providers\AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes(); //Commenting this code works fine
    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15)); //Commenting this code works fine
    Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30)); //Commenting this code works fine
}
```

In the AuthServiceProvider, If I comment the three lines, my token is generated and I am able to generate the token and parse the token for the user.

I have altered the user migration table too.

**database\migrations\2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->string('slug', 60)->unique()->default('');
        $table->string('email', 100)->unique();
        $table->string('mobile', 10)->unique();
        $table->text('password');
        $table->boolean('is_blocked')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
});
```

I have removed `remember_token` and added slug, mobile and is_blocked.

Clarification required is why I get an error from passport:routes(). How can I avoid it?

How to create a client id.

I am using laravel 5.8 and referring to [this url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#managing-clients)

Comment: Share Error message